# Typescript error This condition will always return 'true' since the below type has no overlap

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am getting below error even by adding. can someone guide me or make some code changes so that the program executes as expected

```
Error: src/app/product/product.component.html:21:45 - error TS2367: This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'Observable<Product[]>' and 'number' have no overlap.

21 <table class = "table table-hover" *ngIf = "products != 0">
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/product/product.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppState } from './../app.state';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  products : Observable<Product[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.products = this.store.select(state => state.product)
   }

addProduct(name: any, price: any){
  this.store.dispatch({
    type : 'ADD_PRODUCT',
    payload : <Product>{
      name : name,
      price : price
    }
  });
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class = "table table-hover" *ngIf = "products != 0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Product Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let product of products | async">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `products` is an `Observable<Product[]>`, not a number, so `products != 0` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something here

```
<table class = "table table-hover" *ngIf = "products != 0">
```

The error tells you that the condition its going to be always true because `products` is of type `Observable<Product[]>` and `0` is a number, and obviously they are diferent.

Maybe you want to go with this

```
<table class = "table table-hover" *ngIf = "(products | async).length != 0">
```

Here the condition is asking if the length of the array returned by the Observable products is not 0. You can use the `someObservable | async` when you want to retrieve the value emitted by an Observable in the template.